# Cannot login after installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my new Dell Inspiron 3593

Tags: dell

just bought a new Dell Inspiron 3593 with Ubuntu pre-installed.
Unfortunately, when following the installation procedure the installer crashed; in addition it was also not possible to get an error report out of the system.

Hence, I decided to download the latest Ubuntu distribution 18.04.3, using balena etcher onto a USB flash drive.

All went well, installation could be completed, could remove USB flash drive and prompt with "ENTER".

However, after rebooting the system, I was not able to logon with my password.
Have done the whole procedure several times, different USB flash drives, always the same outcome.

To me (without being able to do run any analytics because I cannot even enter the system), it seems as if during the setup not all login details are archived properly, hence no access.

Any help more than appreciated.
Thanks a lot!
Beat

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the same situation, mentioned below:-

Pressed **CTRL+ALT+F3** to login to a terminal console and just update and upgrade the apt repository and packages by below commands:-

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After this just press **CTRL+ALT+F1** and try to login again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your support. by now I found another way of solving the issue which was intalling Linux Mint.

In case you know how to activate the brightness control, for example with the F11 or F12 keys, would be fantastic. Would be the very last issue I have with the new system.

Best,
Beat